# Is there a way to add custom work item type programmatically in TFS c#?

Tags: c#, tfs, .net-4.5

I am able to add Custom Work Item Type in Visual studio with Power Tools.

[image: Via Process Edition]

[image]

I need to automate this.
Able to interact which TFS API by the below code.

```
Uri collectionUri = new Uri(txtPreview.Text);
NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential(txtUserName.Text.Trim(), txtPassword.Text.Trim());
teamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(collectionUri, credential);
teamProjectCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();

WorkItemStore workItemStore = teamProjectCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
Query query = new Query(this.workItemStore,
    " SELECT [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType]," +
    " [System.State], [System.AssignedTo], [System.Title] " +
    " FROM WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType]='" + cmbTFSTypes.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'" +
    "AND [System.TeamProject]='" + cmbProjects.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'" +
    " ORDER BY [System.WorkItemType], [System.Id]"
    );
WorkItemCollection workItemCollection = query.RunQuery();
```

Able to add get fields from TFS work item like User story

```
if(workItemStore.Projects[projectIndex].WorkItemTypes[cmbTFSTypes.SelectedIndex] != null)
{
       foreach (FieldDefinition Fd in workItemStore.Projects[projectIndex].WorkItemTypes[cmbTFSTypes.SelectedIndex].FieldDefinitions)
           {
           }
}
```

From above code allow us to access list of fields. If some custom field says "XId" is not available , need to add to TFS then make enter to "User story"

Kindly Help.

Comment: Automate what exactly? You have to design the process template manually, there's no getting around that

Comment: There's no way to do that, you have to create your own work item type. Work Item types are created through XML.

Answer (score 3):

You can automatically add an work item type by using the [witadmin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd312129.aspx) command line tools. Command sample:

```
cd %programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\
witadmin importwitd /collection:http://mytfs:8080/tfs/MyCollection /p:MyTFSProject /f:c:\foo\mycustomworkitemtype.xml
```

Comment: Could you add an example? That would convert your _comment_ into a (possibly correct) _answer_.

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

1. Export work item type template via API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitemtype.export.aspx This method returns a XmlDocument document.
2. Analyze and edit content in XmlDocument document.
3. Import work item type template via API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitemtypecollection.import.aspx

Comment: Will it add to all collection, Project in TFS?